# Decrypt the following messages encrypted using the caesar cipher f(p)=(p+3) mode 26

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Decrypt the following messages encrypted using the Caesar cipher $f(p)=(p+3)\; mod\;$26

Alphabet: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,......,Z

Entered HDW GLP VXP

my answer is: KGZ JOS YAS

but my answer is wrong

Comment: decrypt $d(p) = p-3 \pmod{26}$

Comment: encrypt(ORIGINAL)->RULJLQDP.  But encrypt(RULJLQDP) -> UXOMOTGS $\ne$ ORIGINAL.  We have to go *back* the other direction to decrypt.  decript(RULJLQDP) -> ORIGINAL.  If encrypt is f(p) = p+3 mod 26, what is decrypt?.  Hint:  decrypt(p + 3 mod 26) = p.   ... Mmmm your code makes me hungry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. I think you encrypted the already encrypted message. What function decrypts?

Answer (score 0):

**!!DECRYPT!!** the following messages encrypted using the Caesar cipher f(p)=(p+3)mod

26

Alphabet: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,......,Z

Final message (**AFTER** it was encrypted) is: HDW GLP VXP

my answer is: KGZ JOS YAS

but my answer is wrong

====

The **ORIGINAL** message was ??????.  It was !!**EN**!!crypted by adding 3 so to get HDW GLP VXP.

So we need ??? ??? ???  ---- +3 ----->  HDW GLP VXP

What you did was ??? ??? ???  ----- +3 -------> HDW GLP VXP ------ + 3  -----> KGZ JOS YAS

You need to do the opposite to go *BACK* to the original

??? ??? ??? <----- -3 ------- HDW GLP VXP <------ - 3  ----- KGZ JOS YAS

Hint: It's about food.

Comment: Absolutely. But to lapse or distracted interpretations, most people or perhaps even Einstein, Gauss, and Euler on some occasion of their precious lives. Chinese food is very good at good restaurants. And it is very bad in bad ones.